# Body Mass Index program in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a simple program in Haskell that can determine someone's body mass index.

Here's what I have written:

```
type Height = Float
type Weight = Float
type PeopleStats = [(String, Height, Weight)]
```

and...

```
bmi :: Height -> Weight -> Float
bmi heightCm weightKg = weightKg/(heightCm)^2

healthy :: Height -> Weight -> Bool
healthy heightCm weightKg | 25 > index && 18 < index = True
                          | otherwise                = False
  where index = bmi heightCm weightKg
```

So far, the function "healthy" can calculate someone's BMI, and the function "healthyPeople" returns a boolean statement determining if the person's BMI falls within the limits which is considered normal for a healthy person.

I want to write a function called "healthyPeople".

```
healthyPeople :: PeopleStats -> [String]
```

This function needs to take a list of PeopleStats and returns a list of names (Strings) of people who are deemed to be "healthy" from the "healthy" function.

For example:

If I input `[("Lee", 65, 185), ("Wang", 170, 100), ("Tsu", 160, 120)]` I will get a list of the names of the people whose BMI returns true form the boolean function in "healthy".

Please help !!!!

Comment: You seem to have lost some indentation in the definition of `healthy`. The heights and weights for the example people also look unusual.

Answer (score 5):

First, I think you probably meant to define `bmi` as:

```
bmi :: Height -> Weight -> Float
bmi heightCm weightKg = weightKg/(heightCm/100)^2
```

since the formula uses height in meters.

Now, here's a step by step way to do it using helper functions. I defined a type:

```
type PersonStats = (String, Height, Weight)
```

and some functions on that type:

```
healthyPerson :: PersonStats -> Bool
healthyPerson (name, h, w) = healthy h w

getName :: PersonStats -> String
getName (name, h, w) = name
```

With those in place, the final function becomes trivial:

```
healthyPeople :: PeopleStats -> [String]
healthyPeople people = map getName $ filter healthyPerson people
```

or in point-free notation:

```
healthyPeople :: PeopleStats -> [String]
healthyPeople = map getName . filter healthyPerson
```

First you filter out the healthy people from the list, then you map the list of stats into a list of names.
You can express the entire function in one go without the helpers if you use lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

There's a standard Haskell function named `filter` that does exactly (well, almost) what you want here. It has type `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`, i.e., it takes a predicate and a list and returns the members that satisfy the predicate.

You can't apply it directly to `PeopleStats` because the types don't match up, but it's not hard to write a function to connect the two:

```
healthyPerson :: (String, Height, Weight) -> Bool
healthyPerson (_, h, w) = healthy h w

healthyPeople :: [(String, Height, Weight)] -> [String]
healthyPeople people = map name $ filter healthyPerson people
  where name (s, _, _) = s
```

This does what you want.

Comment: do it point free too: `healthyPeople = map name . filter healthyPerson`

Answer (score 0):

First off, note that your definition of BMI is incorrect - you need to convert centimetres into metres:

```
bmi heightCm weightKg = weightKg/(heightCm/100)^2
```

With that fixed, I came up with the following:

```
healthyPeople :: PeopleStats -> [String]
healthyPeople [] = []
healthyPeople ((name, height, weight):xs) | healthy height weight = name : healthyPeople xs
                                          | otherwise = healthyPeople xs
```

This is fairly straight forward. It uses [list-based recursion](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Recursion#List-based_recursion) to recurse over all the elements of the list, and it uses guards similarly to how you used them in the healthy function to switch behaviour based on whether the person at the head of the list is healty or not. If they are healthy, their name is [concatted with](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/List_processing) the result of processing the rest of the list.

Next time, you should try solving the problem yourself and *then* ask for help (and show what you've tried). You'll learn far more!

Comment: If you're prepending to a list, you ought to use `x:`, not `[x] ++`, to avoid constructing and then ignoring a whole extra list.

Comment: @Antal Thanks. It's been quite a while since I touched Haskell, `[x] ++` didn't sit right with me but I couldn't figure out why :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about what you want to do.  You have a list, and you want to (a) select only certain items from the list, and (b) do something to each element of the list.  This being Haskell, let's express this in types.  The first thing you need—well, it'll have to take a list `[a]`, and a way to check if each element is good.  How can it check?  Well, it should be a function `a -> Bool`.  And it should give us back a smaller list.  In other words, something like `[a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]`.  Then we want to take our list and do something to each element.  In other words, we'll need a list `[a]`, and a function `a -> b`.  Thus, we'll want something of the type `[a] -> (a -> b) -> [b]`.  Now that we have the types, we're golden: we can use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to search for them.  I *highly*, highly recommend using Hoogle regularly; it's a Haskell search engine which searches both *types*—the uniquely awesome part—and function/datatype/typeclass/module/package names.  The [first function](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=%5Ba%5D+%2D%3E+%28a+%2D%3E+Bool%29+%2D%3E+%5Ba%5D), as it turns out, is the second result for the query: `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`.  This takes a function and a list and returns only the elements of the list for which the function is true.  The [second function](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=%5Ba%5D+%2D%3E+%28a+%2D%3E+b%29+%2D%3E+%5Bb%5D) is the first result, `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, which calls the given function on every element of the given list and returns a list of the results.  Note that the arguments have the function, not the list, first; this is more natural, as you'll see shortly.

We want to put these two together for `healthyPeople`:

```
healthyPeople :: PeopleStats -> [String]
healthyPeople sts = map (\(n,_,_) -> n) $ filter (\(_,h,w) -> healthy h w) sts
```

This does what you want.  `$` is function application, but effectively groups the right-hand side because of its precedence; this allows us to elide parentheses.  Here we see why it's nice to have `map` take its function first; we pass it the name-extracting function (`(n,_,_)` is a pattern which will match a triple and assign `n` its first element, ignoring the other two), and then (via `$`) the filtered list.

This is nice, but not how I'd actually write it.  Since `sts` is the last parameter to the function and to its body, it's unnecessary.  In truth, all functions in Haskell take only one argument; this means that if you don't pass enough arguments, you get a function which expects the missing arguments and returns the result.  With the help of the function-composition operator `.`, this gives us

```
healthyPeople :: PeopleStats -> [String]
healthyPeople = map (\(n,_,_) -> n) . filter (\(_,h,w) -> healthy h w)
```

And that's probably how I'd write it!  You'll find yourself using `map` and `filter` a lot; they're real workhorses in functional programming.

There is another idiomatic way you can write `healthyPeople`; you can use a list comprehension, as follows:

```
healthyPeople :: PeopleStats -> [String]
healthyPeople stats = [n | (n,h,w) <- stats, healthy h w]
```

This reads as "construct the list of every `n` such that `(n,h,w)` is an element of `stats` and `healthy h w` is true.  If any of the pattern matches or the predicates fail (you can have more than one of each, though you don't need that here), that element is skipped; otherwise, the left side of the `|` is executed.  It's effectively another way of writing the `map`/`filter` version.

---

**Edit 1:** As many others are saying, your units are off in `bmi`; you should have `heightCm/100`.  Also, your `healthy` function has code equivalent to

```
f x | cond      = True
    | otherwise = False
```

This is equivalent to writing, in a C-like,

```
bool f(some_type x) {
  if (cond)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Instead, you should just write

```
bool f(some_type x) {
  return cond;
}
```

Or, in this case

```
f x = cond
```

This gives you the shorter code

```
healthy :: Height -> Weight -> Bool
healthy heightCm weightKg = let index = bmi heightCm weightKg
                            in 25 > index && 18 < index
```

(You can use a `where` clause too, but here's a `let` just because I like it better :))

Answer (score 0):

```
type Height = Float
type Weight = Float
data PersonStats = PersonStats
  { personName :: String, personHeight :: Height, personWeight :: Weight }

bmi :: Height -> Weight -> Float
bmi heightCm weightKg = weightKg/(heightCm / 100)^2

healthy :: Height -> Weight -> Bool
healthy heightCm weightKg = 25 > index && 18 < index
  where index = bmi heightCm weightKg

healthyPerson :: PersonStats -> Bool
healthyPerson p = healthy (personHeight p) (personWeight p)

healthyPeople :: [PersonStats] -> [String]
healthyPeople = map personName . filter healthyPerson
```